# How to handle multiple Lists and a player inventory

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, collections, interface

```
public interface Character {
    void attack(Weapon toAttackwith);
    void reload(Reloadable reloadObj);

    void useHealthPack();

    void pickup(HealthPack healthPack);
    void pickup(ReloadableWeapon rlWeapon);
    void pickup(CQWeapon closeQweapon);
}

public interface Weapon {
    void attack();
}

public interface Reloadable {
     void replenish (final int amount);
}

List<ReloadableWeapon> reloadWeaponsList = new ArrayList<ReloadableWeapon>();
ReloadableWeapon chargeGun = new ReloadableWeapon("Charge Gun",10);
reloadWeaponsList.add(chargeGun);

public final class ReloadableWeapon implements GameItem, Reloadable, Weapon {}

public final class CQWeapons implements GameItem, Weapon {}
```

I have a problem where I have multiple weapons, however, not all are reloadable(ex. Swords) which means I have to store them in a specific `List<ReloadableWeapon>`. If I were to store all of them in a `List<Weapon>` list, I wouldn't be able to call replenish if necessary.

This means for every type of Weapon type that implements a specific `interface` I have to create a `List` for it. For example, close quarters weapons(Swords). I would also have to update my Character interface with specific pickup/use methods for those items.

Is there a better approach? Maybe a specific design pattern? Would the visitor pattern be valid in this case?

Comment: Well, you could assume all weapons are reloadable, and things like swords have an "infinite" clip and simply don't reload. It would probably be cleaner to handle this within a class-level design rather than abstracting to numerous types of weapons (actually try implementing a few weapons first and tweaking a design around that). Additionally, your interfaces should more describe _how_ an object is, things like `#pickup` would accept a `Pickupable` for example, rather than numerous different types.

Comment: @Rogue - Problem is that now i only have what ever methods Pickable allows. Should I rename  my methods then?

Comment: *plugs his lightsaber-sword into outlet to reload it* ... do you need to have interfaces which signal if a weapon is reloadable? Would it be sufficient to have a class / interface `weapon` which has a boolean `reloadable`?

Comment: @hamena314 - If true, has a reloadable method, if not, no need to worry, and I just check the boolean, simple!

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't shoot yourself in the foot this way unless you needed the abstraction to keep something simple/relate some unrelated things. E.g. `Pickupable` would be nice, because that can describe health packs, weapons, ammo, etc (and can provide the needed info to add to inventory). However `Reloadable` is not, because that just describes weapons. We can chuck that into a `Weapon` class, and save ourselves the headache of an extra 40 interfaces

Comment: @Rogue - Not necessarily, while it isn't proper english, bottles/containers be reloadable, we just say refilled. so Reloadable could apply to certain game items

Comment: Sure, and then that might be an appropriate context to do it. But there is usually a bit of a distinction between reloading a gun and refilling containers, enough so that they'll typically have different behaviors. We're talking high-level anyhow, the point is that you don't want to really abstract now what you don't need; the `Reloadable` etc interfaces are usually more of an afterthought and tacked on / mixin'd to classes which need the functionality. As you have more concrete implementations, the areas which need abstraction will become apparent.

Comment: @Rogue - Would a solution like hamena314 suggested be appropriate?

Comment: Largely, no. Mostly because it isn't solving the underlying problem (numerous interfaces / spaghetti design) and just chucks all the data into a list. Partly because you shouldn't have collections with differing types in them (depending on how abstracted these weapons get).

Comment: @Rogue - How would you refactor this?

Comment: I would start by writing a few concrete implementations to work my design against. For the basics, a gun might have things like `getAmmoCount`, `reload`, `getCurrentAmmo`, etc. I see things like the numerous `#pickup` methods and think "What if we had an interface to describe all of those?", hence `Pickupable`. Those are the kind of cleanups you're looking for really.

Comment: @Rogue - How would they be stored in the inventory as the proper type? would you cast it? For example Pickable ammo = new Ammo(5); if the Ammo had getters for the amount, how would i access those? what would the List type?

Comment: If you had a list of weapons, then it'd be `List<Weapon>`, if you had a list of ammo, it'd be `List<Ammo>`. If you have a list of multiple things to be picked up, `List<Pickupable>`. You can adapt these classes to be what you need when you create them, but you realistically aren't going to see a ton of situations where these are going to be stored this way. If you really want to move up the data model a little, you could attempt to abstract the data away from the behavior (e.g. load guns from a json file or db, and behave on that).

Comment: @Rogue - Wouldn't it be the same problem though having to update my character interface to handle ammo? and pickable?

Comment: Well, you have to write those methods first. A lot of these questions go away with code in hand. E.g. `Pickupable` might have a method `#getItems` which returns what the value of it is. At some point you have to stop asking "what if" and just write some code, and work out the issues when they actually happen (instead of anticipating every possible _small_ code issue).

Comment: @Rogue - I'll ask one more question before writing some code :D. Let's say I follow your approach and do pickable.getItems(), it would return what value it is, and I would safely cast it, is that the idea?

Comment: No need for a cast, pretend `#getItems` returns a `List<ItemStack>` where the items (aka ItemStack) are for your inventory. Fit it for your need, casting shouldn't really be a big thing in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using object composition technique, you can solve this problem.

```
List<IWeapon> weapons = new List<IWeapon>();
weapons.Add(new Weapon(new Reloadable());
weapons.Add(new Weapon(new Unreloadable());

//Call weapon[0].replenish and weapon[1].replenish will have different behavior in this way.

public class Reloadable implements IReloadable {
    public void replenish (final int amount){
        //Do something.
    }
}

public class Unreloadable implements IReloadable {
    public void replenish (final int amount){
        //Maybe tell the player that he cannot reload with this weapon.
    }
}

public final class Weapon implements GameItem, IWeapon {
    IReloadable _reloadable;

    public Weapon(IReloadable reloadable){
        _reloadable = reloadable;
    }

    public void replenish (final int amount){
        _reloadable.replenish(amount);
    }
}
```

You could also put a boolean of reloadable in your weapon class as a property. However, you have to use if statement when you reload the weapon which is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

You could store all your weapons in a single list. Then cast to the correct class when needed. For example, if you want to reload all your weapons:

```
for(Weapon w:weapons){
   if(w instanceof ReloadableWeapon){
      ReloadableWeapon rw = (ReloadableWeapon) w;
      //do some reloading
   }
}
```

Comment: Problem is, I read in numerous places that instanceof is bad practice. That's why I suggested if the visitor pattern would be valid.

Comment: `instanceof` itself isn't really a bad practice, but throwing everything of different types into a single collection is.

Comment: You will also find some claiming your entire code will break in C if you use a goto statement, sometimes bad practices are acceptable. The advantage of this method is that if you add an interface of shootable weapons, you can still use one list. And if you want a separate list for each list, the number of lists wil grow very rapidly